# Align 2xX plate on "sandwiched" brick (height of 5 plates)

Tags: building, snot

I'm using "baseplates" for my builds which are built by using two 16x16 plates with one brick height between them (to connect multiple baseplates with Technic bricks and pins).

Now I'd like to build "edges" on the sides where no further baseplate is connected. The problem is, that, although the baseplates have a height of a 2xX plate, I cannot align them correctly centered.

[image]

Is there any SNOT technique to get the 2xX plate aligned as for (A) which I cannot use, because modified brick 32952 does not fit between the two plates of the baseplate. For variants (B) modified brick 87087, and (C) Technic brick with modified tile with pin 2460 the attached plate would be slightly displaced.

[image]

It doesn't matter whether the attached plate would be "studs out" as in (B) or "studs in" as in (C), as long as it aligns as in (A).

(Bonus points if all bricks needed are available in white.)

Comment: Does attached element should be the of same thickness as a plate? What if the was one stud thick with no Technic pins visible?

Comment: It seems like you're inventing your own way of building baseplates, when at least two fairly widely used standards (Moduverse and MILS) exists. Consider just using one of those standards.

Comment: I've seen the MILS standard some time ago, which inspired me for by base plates. Although, they are quite similar (MILS with a base plate as bottom plate and Moduverse with one additional plate layer -- if I'm right). I guess you would have similar problems with both of them when designing an "off-module" edge as with my design? Or are their height a better fit? (Mine, at least, is exactly the height of a 2xX plate ...)

Comment: It might be an addition in Moduverse+, but edges exists for Moduverse (I don't really care about that myself, but I've seen that)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found one solution using [Bracket 2 x 2 - 1 x 2 Centered](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41682), where perpendicular plate is actually centered and fit two plates on each side seamlessly.

[image]

[image]

My other idea, which I had in mind initially, was to use [Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Pin](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2458#T=C), which can fit existing Technic bricks in your baseplates and leave presentable back side without any pins visible. Benefit of such solution is that you can have your baseplates same on each and every side (you don't need to make specific "edge" baseplates), thus allowing you to shuffle them however you like as this solution would work with any of them.

[image]

Comment: Wow. I didn't "find" that bracket, although I've already worked with it! Also in combination with the second option I could build a "pluggable" edge part without modifying the whole base plate. That's excellent!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps too straightforward but how about simply sticking a brick out with 1 stud and attach any kind of bracket to the top or bottom of the protruding end of the brick ?

[image]